# Using a function in php - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, function, return

```
$users = [
    "Andrew",
    "Max",
    "Larry",
    "Ricardo",
    "Lucy",
    "Marcus",
    "Sophie"
];

$sector_rel = [];
$location_rel = []; 

function sectorRel($user){
    return sector_rel[] = round(1/rand(1,10),3);
}

function locationRel($user){
    return $location_rel[] = round(1/rand(1,20),3);
}


foreach($users as $user){
    sectorRel($user);
    locationRel($user);
}
```

Comment: you need to refine your question. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior and a specific problem or error.

Comment: `$sector_rel` and `$location_rel` won't be populated after the for loop ends(if that's what you are expecting) because they are under the global scope

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
function sectorRel($user){
    return sector_rel[] = round(1/rand(1,10),3);
}
```

Should be/could be:

```
function sectorRel($user){
    global sector_rel;
    sector_rel[] = round(1/rand(1,10),3);
}
```

The problem is that the functions don't have access to the array variables. You can import them into the function scope using the keyword **global**, if they are indeed global variables. Now, having global variables isn't a good thing, and for a small test it's okay, but eventually you'll be eliminating your globals and this solution won't work.

But alternatively, you could pass the array variables to the function as an argument. However, this still introduces a lot of logic in the function. The function has to be told about the array, it must know that it needs to add a value to the end, and it also needs to calculate the actual value to add.

So better, make the function just return the calculated value and add it to the array outside of the function:

```
function sectorRel($user){
    // Assuming your are going to use 'user' here somewhere?
    return round(1/rand(1,10),3); 
}

function locationRel($user){
    return round(1/rand(1,20),3);
}

foreach($users as $user){
    sector_rel[] = sectorRel($user);
    $location_rel[] = locationRel($user);
}
```

You can then wrap this entire snippet of code into another function and call that to populate the arrays. That way, you've quite reasonably split the responsibilities of the functions and have a piece of code that looks nice and clean.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `return` in either of `sectorRel` or `locationRel`. At the moment this will return the reference to that array and it is not being stored in a variable. You would need to store them in a variable or just get rid of the return. My PHP is a little weak at the moment but you should probably append the values in those functions to the array.

Also if you have a parameter called $user for each of those functions you should either use that parameter or just get rid of it.